# Cardinality of the smallest subgroup containing two distinct subgroups of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$  is  a  finite  group  and  $H_1$,$H_2$  are  two  disjoint  subgroups  of  order $2$. $H$  is  the subgroup  of  smallest  order that  contains  both  $H_1$  and  $H_2.$ What  is  the  cardinality  of  $H$ $?$

$A.$ always $2$.

$B.$ always $4.$

$C.$ always $8.$

$D.$ none of the above.

Now I know , $A.$  cannot  be  as  that  would  not let them stay disjoint anymore.

$C.$  is  not  true  if  you  think  of  the  group  $K_4$ of  cardinality  $4$.

Now  problem  is  option  $B.$  Can there  be  any  such  $H$  that  has  cardinality $\neq 4$ $?$

What is  it  then $?$

Comment: In question i think it should be distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $H_1 = \{e, h_1\}$ and $H_2 = \{e, h_2\}$, what happens if $h_1$ and $h_2$ don't commute?

Comment: There  comes more than $4$ elements.

Answer (score 4):

The two subgroups are $H_1 = \{1,x\}$ and $H_2 = \{1,y\}$, essentially (with $x^2 = y^2 = 1$). They're not really disjoint, as all subgroups contain $1$, so I assume we mean that they're disjoint except for that.

So we get in $H$ the elements $1, x, y, xy, yx, xyx, yxy, \ldots$. There is no natural upper limit (because $xy$ and $yx$ need not have order 2). I think we can go as high as we like using $x$ and $y$ reflections in the plane, and $xy$ becomes a rotation, and we can get lots of finite orders for that...)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $G$ is a dihedral group (symmetry group of a regular polygon), then it is generated by two (suitable) reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Option $B$  won't  work . Take  this  example  **:**

$G=S_4$ ; $H_1=\{e,(1\ 2)\}$; $H_2=\{e,(1\ 3)\}$